# To combine two or more different regex expressions in a single condition

Tags: sql, regex, tableau-api

I need to perform below two expressions in a single THEN statement in IF clause.

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT_NTH([Col_name],'.*>(.*)',1)

REGEXP_REPLACE([Col_name],'(".*")\s',"")
```

both the operations should be checked using OR operation.

Sample:

```
<E05739> A service with name "1,178,302,180" is already active between Fri Apr 21 00:00:00 2017 and Thu Dec 30 00:00:00 9999.
```

Expected Output:

```
A service with name  is already active between Fri Apr 21 00:00:00 2017 and Thu Dec 30 00:00:00 9999.
```

Comment: Please check my approach in the answer below, the `REGEXP_REPLACE([Col_name],'pattern','$1$2')` should work (or, if `'$1$2'` does not work, try POSIX/Python style, `'\1\2'`)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following regex replace operation:

```
^<[^>]*>\s*(.*?)"[0-9,]+"(.*)
```

to replace with `$1$2`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EOXdqn/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `<[^>]*>` - a `<...>` substring (`<` + 0 or more chars other than `>` and then `>`)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group #1 (referenced to with `$1` from the replacement pattern) capturing any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `"` - a double quote
- `[0-9,]+`  - 1 or more digits or `,`
- `"` - a `"`
- `(.*)` - Capturing group #2 (referenced to with `$2` from the replacement pattern) capturing any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible (greedy quantifier `*` is used here).